# How to trace all ActiveX/COM objects life cyle in an ASP application?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, memory-leaks

I'm fighting to find a memory leak in an old ASP application. I'm not the designer of this application (please kill me if one day I produce such an horror) moreover I'm far from being an ASP/JavaScript guru.

I'm supposing that some ActiveX/COM objects are not freed correctly but it's huge job to trace all allocations. Some of them are specifically designed in C++ for this application and I could trace their life cycle easier but many others are ADODB.Recordset or Microsoft.XMLDOM.

So my question is, do you know a generic way to trace globally all ActiveX objects life time of an ASP application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [IISState](http://www.iisfaq.com/default.aspx?view=P197) will help. You may get some insight from inspecting the output files it makes.